# Uninitialized string offset error handling

Tags: php

I have a variable name `$accountNumber` which holds a 9 digit number. When a user types it in and when it is displayed, it is cut up in 9 separate box's.

Like so:
[image: how the account number is displayed]

When getting the account number I do something like this:

```
//$data['acountNumber'] = 453554334;

$accountNumber = (string)$data['accountNumber'];
$accountNumber_0 = $accountNumber[0];
$accountNumber_1 = $accountNumber[1];
$accountNumber_2 = $accountNumber[2];
$accountNumber_3 = $accountNumber[3];
$accountNumber_4 = $accountNumber[4];
$accountNumber_5 = $accountNumber[5];
$accountNumber_6 = $accountNumber[6];
$accountNumber_7 = $accountNumber[7];
$accountNumber_8 = $accountNumber[8];
```

However, if I don't have an account number listed, I get an ***Uninitialized string offset*** error. I can make this "go away" if I add an `@` in font of each `$accountNumber[#]` but I thought I would ask you guys if there is a better way at handling this.

What do you think?

**EDIT - After accepted answer**

The below answers work great. But since I needed to have my array be size 9 no matter what, I found that this works best.

`$accountNumber = array_pad(str_split($data['accountNumber']), 9, '');`

Comment: Try checking if it's there with `isset`?

Comment: I could @techhouse, but it would be so much easier to just add an `@`. Is there a reason I wouldn't want to use an `@` and instead of having to have code declare the variables twice?

Comment: Well, `@` will simply mute it and will give you headaches when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not converted the string to array. `str_split` would do that for you.

This should work for you:

```
<?php

$data['acountNumber'] = 453554334;
$data['acountNumber'] = strval($data['acountNumber']); // converts numbers to string

$accountNumber = str_split($data['acountNumber']); // split the string to array
$accountNumber_0 = $accountNumber[0];
$accountNumber_1 = $accountNumber[1];
$accountNumber_2 = $accountNumber[2];
$accountNumber_3 = $accountNumber[3];
$accountNumber_4 = $accountNumber[4];
$accountNumber_5 = $accountNumber[5];
$accountNumber_6 = $accountNumber[6];
$accountNumber_7 = $accountNumber[7];
$accountNumber_8 = $accountNumber[8];
```

Here is a [PHP Fiddle](http://3v4l.org/n0QDY) that shows it in action.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Cast your string
$accountNumber = (string)$data['accountNumber'];
//Get the length of the string
$length = strlen ($accountNumber);
//Create an empty array containing the account numbers
$accountNumberArr = array();
//Start the loop
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    //Add the account numbers to the account number array
    $accountNumberArr['accountNumber_'.$i] = $accountNumber[$i];
}

//Now you can access your account number as follows
// $accountNumberArr['accountNumber_0'], $accountNumberArr['accountNumber_1'];
```

Comment: thank's for your answer. your method works great too. I would prefer to use str_split like @Guns stated but your `accountNumberArr` is also helped me out a lot